# Bleed resistor with a load that can be turned off

Tags: power-supply, load

I have simple AC to DC 40 W, 18 VDC power supply with a bleeder resistor to drain the caps. However, the load can be turned off of independently of the power supply. This means the bleed resistor heats up while in normal operation rather than only on power-down. I don't know much about this and not sure if,

- a. I should care - let it heat up and take the load.
- b. Remove the bleed resistor so the circuit is open when the load is turned off - I'd prefer to keep it.
- c. Some other solution - switch of the power with an SSR when there's no load or some such?

Comment: You've forgotten to tell us the discharge resistor's resistance, its power rating, the supply capacitance  and your discharge time requirement (which will best be defined by a time constant to decrease by 63%). Hit the [edit] link below your question ...

Comment: `This means the bleed resistor now heats up while consuming power rather than doing its job.` Sorry, but really I can't understand: The bleeder resistors are in parallel with capacitors, right? They always consume power regardless the load is connected or not (P = V²/R). So, how do they heat up when the load is disconnected/turned off?

Comment: I'd guess that the word "now" is erroneous. My guess is that it always heated up when the mains power was on.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about how the load is enabled? (what the control signal looks like)?

Comment: Sounds like your bleed resistor is too low. It forms an RC circuit, so you can calculate a suitable R to discharge the caps in a reasonable amount of time - but if its simply for safety, a few seconds is plenty good enough using a couple K (unless you have hella caps).

Comment: @Will, see if my edit reflects what you're trying to say. Note that in your edit you supplied none of the information requested in my first comment. At this stage a schematic would be helpful too.

Comment: The load is a class d 50w x2 amp. Yes the resistor always gets hot. It's 2.2k 3w resistor in parallel to cap., parallel to load.  Before this is an rc filter. I would like not to have the bleeder resistor using power when the load is off, it should be bleeding the caps.

Answer (score 1):

Bleed resistor is meant to short out your bulk capacitors on the PSU output, so you can touch the output without getting a nasty shock by discharging caps through yourself. Normally caps would self-discharge, but that takes forever, so bleeders are used.

Dropping 18V across 2.2k draws about 8mA. With P=I^2R we get ~150mW. 3W resistor shouldn't get too warm. With 100W load having 0.15% loss due to heat seems a reasonable tradeoff for saving a couple of cents on manufacturing :)

If you don't want bleed resistor wasting power, you should disconnect it from the power path when PSU is on. For that you can use a depletion mode FET in series with bleeder with gate connected to primary input power detection.

All in all it sounds much too complicated for you, if you have to ask about whether bleeder heating is a reason to worry.